# Is There a way to connect to laser scanner of a android device?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My company gave me an Android device with a built-in barcode scanner.

Is there a way to activate the built in scanner from a Flutter app? The device has a hardware key to activate the scanner at any time,
and I want the scanned barcode input into my Flutter app.

Comment: I am working with almost the same device(Sunmi L2). barcode is automatically detected in any focused text filed

Comment: Almost all of QR scanners works as virtual keyboards. Try to scan with focused TextField.

Comment: @rstrelba
thanks,but i don't need keyboard popup in this case,any other solution?

Comment: @BenjithKizhisseri thanks,but i don't need keyboard popup in this case,any other solution?

Comment: @MohsenParvar yes. you can use RawKeyboardListener

Comment: sample code added below

Comment: @BenjithKizhisseri your solution worked before upgrading flutter
can you please give me any complete working sample?
i'm completely stuck

Comment: @BenjithKizhisseri i also found this: https://pub.dev/packages/pda_scanner ,might work for you instead of working with textfield

Answer (score 0):

```
RawKeyboardListener(
        onKey: (key) {
          if (key.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyDownEvent') {


              appState.barcodeTxt.text += key.data.keyLabel;

              if (appState.barcodeTxt.text.contains('\n')) {
               // your custom `enter key` fun
                appState.switchKeypadListioner(context, 'enter');
              }
            }
          }
        },
        focusNode: appState.barcodeFocusNode,
        child: TextField(
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
           controller: appState.barcodeTxt,
          autofocus: false,
           onSubmitted: (val) {
           // enter key handler
            appState.switchKeypadListioner(context, 'enter');

          },
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,


        ),
      )
```

Comment: Will RawKeyboardListner automatically detect the device(e.g-TaoTronics  USB  BarcodeLaser Scanner) and able to read the bar code? even If I'm running the flutter app on windows, Web?

Comment: Adding some explanation to this answer might make it more useful.